# Embedding 3-rd-party website

Tags: web-applications, embed, embedding

How do I embed (is that even the right word?) a whole 3rd-party website into a web application such that the user can access the full functionality of that particular website within the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iframe to embed any site or(url) into yours. But if response header of that url contains x-frame-options: deny, then it will show blank. This is done to let owner of a website decide if and where they want their site to be embed.